# jQuery scroll to ID script only scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm using the following to make any anchor with the class of `.jump-link` scroll to the ID it's referencing in the `href` attribute:

```js
// Scroll to ID
$('.jump-link').click(function () {
    var el = $(this).attr('href'),
        elWrapped = $(el);
    scrollToId(elWrapped, 40);
    return false;
});
function scrollToId(element, navheight) {
    var offset = element.offset(),
        offsetTop = offset.top,
        totalScroll = offsetTop - navheight;
    $('body,html').animate({
        scrollTop: totalScroll
    }, 500);
}
```

Unfortunately though it only seems to work scrolling **down** the page. I'd also like the script to work scrolling up the page.

Comment: Your saying that, it is scrolling down the page always,irrespective of the ID mentioned?

Comment: [Works both ways here](http://jsfiddle.net/447j6/). You need to isolate your issue further because the problem is not reproducible based on what you've given so far.

Comment: When I isolate the issue ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alecrust/MY7tb/)) it seems to work as expected. Very strange.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.. It will be work.

```
$(".jump-link").click(function(){
 var id = $(this).attr('href');
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#"+id).offset().top}, 2000);
});
```

Comment: It will be difficult to point out what you need to change when the broken part of your code is not included in your question.

Comment: I am not sure why not working this but used this script its working fine for me.

Comment: Look on www.pelicansdesign.com

Answer (score 0):

here is the code try this

```
$(function() {
    $('ul.nav a').bind('click',function(event){
        var $anchor = $(this);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
        }, 1200);
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: you implement your `id` or `class` however you using show me a fiddle for fix the problem it will definetly work

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $(".scroll").click(function(event){     
                event.preventDefault();
                $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:$(this.hash).offset().top},1200);
            });
        });
    </script>
```